# c# using for loop to write out an array

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I need to write out my array using a for-loop. This is my code. The reason I have to do it with a for-loop is because it is for a school project and the teacher does not accept anything else. What the code is doing right now is that first it creates an array with random numbers and make sure there are no duplicates then it makes sure it is sorted with bigger numbers first.

```
int[] myArray = new int[20];

Random random = new Random();
bool isUnique;

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++) {
    isUnique = false;

    while (!isUnique) {
        isUnique = true;
        myArray[i] = random.Next(1, 100);

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (myArray[i] == myArray[j]) {
                isUnique = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool isSorted;
int change;

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++) {
    isSorted = false;

    while (!isSorted) {
        isSorted = true;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < myArray.Length; j++) {
            if (myArray[i] < myArray[j]) {
                change = myArray[j];
                myArray[j] = myArray[i];
                myArray[i] = change;
                isSorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the extra text to explain what your problem is? What doesn't work?

Comment: You are not writing it out anywhere.  Also, if you find yourself having to explain what your code does it's generally a hint that you may need to refactor.  In your case, encapsulating your code into well named methods, such as `CreateArrayWIthRandomNumbers` and `SortArray` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(myArray[i]);
 }
```

Prints your array, it's sorted fine and prints biggest to smallest.

What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code to less verbose variant:

```
int[] myArray = new int[20];
Random random = new Random();
int randomValue = 0;

// Fill array
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    do randomValue = random.Next(1, 100);
    while (myArray.Contains(randomValue));
    myArray[i] = randomValue;
}

// Sort array
myArray = myArray.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();
```

For write array to console you should use cycle:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(myArray[i] + " ");
```

But for best and less verbose result you should use this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myArray));
```

It's return this:

> 97, 95, 93, 92, 91, 85, 84, 78, 77, 76, 75, 68, 57, 45, 24, 22, 14, 10, 8, 4